# Mapping pixels of two matrices

Tags: matlab, dictionary, pixel

Say that I have two matrices of the following sizes:

```
matrix_1 = 30090x2

matrix_2 = 170x177
```

Assume here that the number of `rows` n `matrix_1` represents the number of `pixels`. You can see that the size of `matrix_2` is equal to the number of pixels.

What I'm trying to do is `map` the pixels in `matrix_1` to the pixels in `matrix_2`, such that for example:

```
matrix_1(1) = matrix_2(1)
matrix_1(2) = matrix_2(2)
matrix_1(3) = matrix_2(3)
......
......
matrix_1(n) = matrix_2(n)
```

How can I do that in `matlab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option

```
  matrix_1 = matrix_2(:);
```

which copies the elements (all of them) of `matrix_2` in *one* long column.

In your data you said that `matrix_1` has two columns, you can add a further empty column by doing, for instance

```
  matrix_1  = [matrix_1 zeros(size(matrix_1))];
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast way is first convert both matrix to column vector using the following command:
matrix_1=matrix_1(:);
matrix_2=matrix_2(:);

And since both matrix now have the same size, you can perform wanted operations.

If you need to restore the matrix to original scale, you can do it by using reshape command
matrix_1=reshape(matrix_1, 30090,2)

see following reference:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html